# "Global" exception handler

Tags: .net, visual-studio, vsix

I know how to catch all exceptions (for logging/fixing purposes) on WinForms, WPF and ASP.NET - but where how would I install it on my VSIX package? I can't find anything on MSDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. See [discussion here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/2ab45296-de56-49ae-a81a-a2395811df4c).